# PnP.PowerShell cannot find 'Microsoft.Identity.Client' assembly

Tags: pnp-powershell

Hi I'm stumbling on this issue since this morning.

PowerShell 7.1.4
PnP.PowerShell 1.7.0

`Connect-PnPOnline -Url my-url -Interactive`

> Connect-PnPOnline: Could not load file or assembly
> 'Microsoft.Identity.Client, Version=4.30.1.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=0a613f4dd989e8ae'. Could not find or load a specific
> file. (0x80131621)

I removed and re-installed the Module with the same issue.
I also tried with the nightly build (1.7.46-nightly) with no differences.

The Module is installed in `{my documents}/PowerShell/Modules/Pnp.PowerShell/1.7.0`

Both `Core` and `Framework` subfolders contain the `Microsoft.Identity.Client` file with the requested version (4.30.1.0).

Any help/ideas on how I can proceed?